# How do I build a frontend for my opencv. My aim is to solve a rubik's cube and run the project in a browser window

Tags: javascript, python, flutter, opencv, frontend

I am building a python project using opencv and kociemba library, the aim is to solve a rubik's cube. It would take the 6 faces of cube as input and produce the instructions to solve the cube as output. However, I want to encase my project to run on the web browser and with some GUI like buttons to open/close camera, snap image etc, something like a web app. What should I use to design the browser part of this app and how should I connect python and the other part?

**What I have tried:**

I have researched a little bit about flutter and react native but I am not sure how would I connect my python part to it and input-output process.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache Cordova:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html

Taking a picture:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

Code below is from their documentation:

**Take Picture Example**

Take a photo and retrieve the image's file location:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Take a photo and retrieve it as a Base64-encoded image:

```
/**
 * Warning: Using DATA_URL is not recommended! The DATA_URL destination
 * type is very memory intensive, even with a low quality setting. Using it
 * can result in out of memory errors and application crashes. Use FILE_URI
 * instead.
 */
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 25,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```